# Why Android Volley library is unable to connect asp.net web api?

Tags: android, asp.net, android-volley, webapi

I am trying to call asp.net web api from Android Client using Volley library. The .net API is working fine and listening ports are:
http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001 in my local machine.

But,When, I try to run android client keeping the base url as http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/login
I found below error in console->

```
04/23 23:13:41: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6 API 24.
Install successfully finished in 9 s 435 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.tourexpwip/com.example.tourexpwip.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3662 on device 'Nexus_6_API_24 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.tourexpwip-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/System.out: URL: http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/login/
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa67ec7c0, tid 3662
E/Volley: [210] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 307 for http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/login/
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa67ecac0, tid 3683
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb5c05660: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb5c05660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb5c032b0)
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:201)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb5c05660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb5c032b0)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The controller class for login in ASP.NET web api->

```
namespace TourExpWIP1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        NetCoreAuthenticationContext dbContext = new NetCoreAuthenticationContext();

        public string Post([FromBody] TblUser  value)
        {
            
            if (dbContext.TblUser.Any(user => user.UserName.Equals(value.UserName)))
            {
                TblUser user = dbContext.TblUser.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(value.UserName)).First();
                var client_post_hash_password = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    Common.SaltHashPassword(
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value.Password),
                        Convert.FromBase64String(user.Salt)));
                if (client_post_hash_password.Equals(user.Password))
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
                else return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Wrong Password");
            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("user does not exists in db");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.In Android Manifiest, in tag application add:
inside tag application add this tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
...
/>
```

2.With a corresponding network_security_config.xml in app/src/main/res/xml/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

More details please find from here- [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)